# Find substring in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to check if a specific substring which is in SQL Server column, is contained in a user provided string?

**Example :**

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 'random words to check, which are in a string' CONTAINS Column
```

From my understanding, [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) can't do such kind of search.

**EDIT :**

I have a fully indexed text and would like to search (by the fastest method) if a string provided by me contains words that are present in a column.

Comment: Be aware that you need a [Full Text Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) before you can use `CONTAINS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE 'random words ....' LIKE '%' + t.column + '%'
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.column LIKE '%random words ....%'
```

Depends what did you mean, first one select the records that the column has a part of the provided string. The second one is the opposite.

Comment: I'm looking for the first one, just wanted the fastest method. From what I read, `LIKE` operator isn't the fastest since it can't benefit from indexed columns.

Comment: I'm not having any luck getting results from the first form in either MySQL or sqlite. Is this a SQL Server–specific feature?

Comment: Probably the ‘+’ is the issue. Use Concat instead @davidmoles

Comment: @sagi Aha. `LIKE CONCAT('%', t.column, '%')` does work in MySQL. SQLite doesn't support `CONCAT()`, but it works with the `||` operator: `LIKE '%' || t.column || '%'`. I'm surprised neither threw an error with `+`, just returned an empty result — who knows what they think they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) syntax together with `%` around the string you are looking for:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   table
WHERE
   Column LIKE '%some random string%'
```

This will return all rows in the table `table` in which the column `Column` contains the text "some random string".

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to get data starting with some letter you can use % this operator like this in your where clause

```
WHERE
Column LIKE "%some random string"
```

2) If you want to get data contains any letter you can use

```
WHERE
Column LIKE "%some random string%"
```

3)if you want to get data ending with some letter you can use

```
WHERE
Column LIKE "some random string%"
```